# Foreign key to match the Primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to make appropriate links using the foreign key to match the primary key.

What would be the correct foreign keys?

```
Student(sid integer, sname varchar(20), programme varchar(4), level integer, age integer) 

Class(ccode varchar(6), cname varchar(25), week_day varchar(3), meets_at time, room varchar(6), tid integer) 

Enrolled(sid integer, ccode varchar(6)) 

Tutor(tid integer, tname varchar(20))
```

The meaning of the tables above is obvious: Student stores data about students registered in some 
programme offered by Computing department. Each class identified by the ccode (which is the its 
code) is taught by a tutor identified by tid. Enrolled has one row per each pair student-class, for 
each student registration in a given class. Tutor stores data about the tutors involved in teaching. 
Note that all the names of students and tutors consist in a string formed of the last name preceded 
by a first (and possibly a middle) name. The primary keys are underlined.

Comment: and where is the primary key?

Comment: Oops I thought I had made the primary key bold. There!

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the correct foreign keys?

Student sid (PK) with Enrolled sid (FK), Class ccode (PK) with Enrolled ccode (FK) and Class tid (PK) with Tutor tid (FK).

Ideally you should have another level of separation to take into account the possibility that a class is given by more than one tutor.

Answer (score 0):

here you have two primary keys sid and ccode
you have another junction table where both of these primary keys are used as foreign keys.
this is correct representation..
i think its okey